# Gradle cannot update successfully from v6.5.1 to v7.0.0

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

I am trying to update my local gradle(out of ide) from 6.5.1 to 7.0.0.

I try two commands from gradle website and network in cmd and path is the root of one of my project(there are gradlew.bat and gradlew files):

```
gradle wrapper --gradle-version=7.0 --distribution-type=all

gradlew wrapper --gradle-version=7.0 --distribution-type all
```

And, i try those commands to check the version

```
gradle -v
gradlew -v
```

The gradlew updates sucessfully. It prints `version 7.0.0`.

However, the version of gradle is still in v6.5.1.

How can I update it without download the v7.0.0 packet and cover the files in disk(I am worrying about that i should download all of my packages again in new gradle)?

ps: the gradle is locating in D:\gradle in my disk and java environment is openJDK 15

Thanks agains

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot update your gradle standalone version without downloading it, and with gradle wrapper you cannot upgrade your gradle installation, it always works on your current project folder (command `gradlew`) only. To upgrade a standalone gradle installation (command `gradle` without the wrapper prefix `w`), you have to manually download the binaries, include the new bin directory in your PATH environment as described [in the manual on the gradle homepage](https://gradle.org/install/#manually), or use a package manager like sdk man, chocolatey, brew etc.

If you are using the gradle wrapper `gradlew` for your builds, it works completely independent from your gradle installation.

Comment: Thanks for answering. uh, the reason that i use the local gradle is i do not want to download gradle-bin again and again when i open a new project. So, the local gradle cannot update itself, need to download and cover those stuff in disk? and the gradlew like the independent env of that project? And, is there a manager for gradle like anaconda(manager of python in windows) in win? thanks again

Comment: @Eritquearcus If you like to use more than one gradle installation and switch between them, you can try to use the GRADLE_HOME environment variable in conjunction with a PATH variable in a small shell script. In our company, we always use the gradle wrapper and put that into the version repository - so no need to most of us to download the gradle installation.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and, in my case, the problem was a running gradle demon using the previous version. Check running demons with:

```
gradle --status
```

Stop the demons with

```
gradle --stop
```

Also I restarted the console/terminal.